# Disabling Multiple buttons with for loop (specific type of loop is not important)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In `C#` `ASP.NET` i have a `html` **page** and i have 30 `buttons` in it **(Button1 ,Button2 ... Button30)** i want to disable all these buttons with a loop,

> like Button[i].enable=false

How can i do that ?
I read a list of `buttons` from my database and i want to disable those have **(false)** values.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DataSet.seatsDataTable seatDT = new DataSet.seatsDataTable();
    DataSetTableAdapters.seatsTableAdapter seatTA = new DataSetTableAdapters.seatsTableAdapter();
    seatTA.FillByAllSeatID(seatDT);
    for(int i = 1; i < 29; i++) {
        seatTA.FillBySeatIDfromUser(seatDT, i);
        if (seatDT[0].SeatStatus == false) {
            reserved.Text += ( seatDT[0].SeatID.ToString() + ",") ;
            //Here i want to change button disable/enable status.
            //like Button[i].enabled=false
        }
    }
}
```

HTML CODE :

```
   <section id="banner">
 <table class="auto-style1" style="align-self: center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button1" type="button" runat="server" value="1" onclick="disable(1)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button2" type="button" runat="server" value="2" onclick="disable(2)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button3" type="button" value="3" runat="server" onclick="disable(3)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button4" type="button" value="4" runat="server" onclick="disable(4)" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button5" type="button" value="5" runat="server" onclick="disable(5)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button6" type="button" value="6" runat="server" onclick="disable(6)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button7" type="button" value="7" runat="server" onclick="disable(7)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button8" type="button" value="8" runat="server" onclick="disable(8)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button9" type="button" value="9" runat="server" onclick="disable(9)" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button10" type="button" value="10" runat="server" onclick="disable(10)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button11" type="button" value="11" runat="server" onclick="disable(11)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button12" type="button" value="12" runat="server" onclick="disable(12)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button13" type="button" value="13" runat="server" onclick="disable(13)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button14" type="button" value="14" runat="server" onclick="disable(14)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button15" type="button" value="15" runat="server" onclick="disable(15)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button16" type="button" value="16" runat="server" onclick="disable(16)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button17" type="button" value="17" runat="server" onclick="disable(17)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button18" type="button" value="18" runat="server" onclick="disable(18)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button19" type="button" value="19" runat="server" onclick="disable(19)" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button20" type="button" value="20" runat="server" onclick="disable(20)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button21" type="button" value="21" runat="server" onclick="disable(21)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button22" type="button" value="22" runat="server" onclick="disable(22)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button23" type="button" value="23" runat="server" onclick="disable(23)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button24" type="button" value="24" runat="server" onclick="disable(24)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button25" type="button" value="25" runat="server" onclick="disable(25)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button26" type="button" value="26" runat="server" onclick="disable(26)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button27" type="button" value="27" runat="server" onclick="disable(27)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button28" type="button" value="28" runat="server" onclick="disable(28)" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Button29" type="button" value="29" runat="server" onclick="disable(29)" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Comment: Sorry,just a mistake in typing. still don't know what to do.

Comment: you tagged javascript and jquery in your question, don't you want to use it? you can disable all your buttons with a single jquery line

Comment: @leo_ap How can i do that ?

Comment: post the view html, so we can see your buttons structure. with it, we can make a selector for jquery

Comment: where is your list of buttons?

Comment: @leo_ap take a look at my html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page.FindControl` is you need.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button b = this.FindControl("button" + i) as Button;
        if (b != null)
            b.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Fix1 for Html input control and runat="server".

`using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;`

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            HtmlInputButton b = this.FindControl("button" + i) as HtmlInputButton;
            if (b != null)
                b.Disabled = !b.Disabled;
        }
```

Comment: This worked but since i'm using HTML Buttons <input type="Button" ... > the command won't find the control . How can i fix that ?

Comment: OK, i fixed it and you can see.

Comment: Gosh! thanx a lot buddy you helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all your buttons is inside a table.

Ok, lets disable all buttons inside that table.

First put a specific id on your table, like this:

```
<table id="buttons-tbl" class="auto-style1" style="align-self: center">
```

and then, put this script on the bottom of your table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#buttons-tbl input[type=button]").prop("disabled", true);
</script>
```

Of course that you will need to include the jquery library in your html